# Serializable class cannot be deserialized

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a graph i want to store in my DB and retrieve it in another package. My graph signature is:

```
public class ModuleToModuleDependencyGraph extends DependencyGraph<ModuleNode, ModuleToModuleDependency> implements Serializable
```

Signature of classes it extends and use :

```
public class DependencyGraph<V extends Node, E extends DependencyEdge<? extends DependencyData>> extends DefaultDirectedGraph<V, E> implements IDependencyGraph<V, E>, Serializable 
public class ModuleNode extends Node implements Serializable
public class ModuleToModuleDependency extends DependencyEdge<ModuleToModuleDependencyData> implements Serializable
```

The code i use to save to database(as BLOB)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos1 = new ObjectOutputStream(bos1);
oos1.writeObject(moduleGraph);
oos1.flush();
oos1.close();
bos1.close();
byte[] graph = bos1.toByteArray();
statement = connectionDB.prepareStatement("INSERT IGNORE INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES (?)");
statement.setObject(1, graph);
```

Code to retrieve from DB

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes("graph"));
ObjectInputStream ins = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
Object O = ins.readObject();
```

I have implemented Serializable in all classes which are related to the graph(edge class for example). While storing in the DB i have no problem but when i try to retrieve it I get

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.mycompany.dpx.dependencytree.ModuleNode; class invalid for deserialization
```

Why am i getting this error? Am i missing something to make the class serializable? 
When i tried to store in DB without making the ModuleNode class implement Serializable it gave me an error that it cannot serialize it, after implementing the interface i get no such error so it means that ModuleNode is serializable right?

UPDATE:

ModuleNode.java:

```
package com.mycompany.dpx.dependencytree;

import com.mycompany.dpx.dependencytree.graph.Node;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ModuleNode extends Node implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1322322139926390329L;
    private String sdfClassName;
    private String moduleClassName;

    public ModuleNode(){
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for ModuleNode
     * @param uid Unique identifier for the module. Immutable.
     */
    public ModuleNode(String uid) {
        super(uid);
        this.sdfClassName = "";
        this.moduleClassName = "";
    }

    /**
     * Set the Source Data Factory class name for the module
     * @param sdfClassName
     */
    public void setSDFClassName(String sdfClassName) {
        this.sdfClassName = sdfClassName;
    }

    /**
     * Get the Source Data Factory class name for the module
     * @return sourceDataFactoryClassName
     */
    public String getSDFClassName() {
        return this.sdfClassName;
    }

    /**
     * Set the ViewModule class name for the module
     * @param moduleClassName
     */
    public void setModuleClassName(String moduleClassName) {
        this.moduleClassName = moduleClassName;
    }

    /**
     * Get the Module class name for the module
     * @return moduleClassName
     */
    public String getModuleClassName() {
        return this.moduleClassName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return super.equals(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please share code for **ModuleNode** class.

Comment: Added the code as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Verify all the super classes of ModuleNode have empty argument constructor Since the exception happened during deserialization.
2. Verify all the ModuleNode super classes implements serializable interface and their serialVersionIds are not changed during deserialization

Comment: Should the interface that the parent classes implement also extend serialization?

Comment: yes from below post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871044/how-can-i-serialize-an-interface

Comment: I tried this as well but still the same error. Is it possible that this error is caused because the ModuleNode class doesn't exist for the other package? The moduleNode class which the package where i am retrieving access is an old version which is not serialiazable but i changed the definition and made it serializable for the database(private checkout) and while retrieving i just want the object so that at least i know that it's getting retrieved.

Comment: I think that is the problem since when it tries to deserialize it calls the class which is outdated and cannot be deserialized. Cause when trying to read the DB from the package which has the updated class i get object fine.

Comment: What do you mean by outdated class version? So if you have serialversionId's in your class you will not face any problem. While serialize a class based on class properties JVM generate Serialversion Id.. In this case if your class has been modified during deserialize then it will throw some exception. so that we are adding serialversion id in the class. Eventhough serialversionId's present removing field and modifying the field data type could not be applicable. changes like adding static, final keywords or introducing  fields are fine.

Comment: By outdated class version I mean that the class in prod is not serializable so I checked it out and made it so. Now I have another package which is deserializing the bytes it received from db but when it deserialize it access the class in prod which is not serializable thus it throws an error.